# GeoPandas sjoin with extensive quantities

Tags: python, spatial-join, geopandas, dissolve, overlay

I have one geodataframe that contains polygons and corresponding land use category (e.g. agricultural, commercial, retail, residential, ...) and another that contains census tract polygons and corresponding population.  I want to bring the population data from the 2nd dataframe into the first dataframe.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
gdf_chi_pop = gpd.sjoin(gdf_chi, gdf_census, how='inner',op='intersects')
```

The problem is that `gdf_chi_pop` has a bunch of extra polygons that don't exist in `gdf_chi`, which is not what I'm wanting.  I just want a new dataframe with populations for all the polygons that already exist in `gdf_chi`.  What I also need to know is how geopandas differentiates between intensive properties (e.g. temperature, sunny days per year, population density, fraction of dogs that are poodles) and extensive properties (e.g. population, number of poodles, number of stores that sell spatulas) in polygons when doing sjoin.

Comment: Try intersecting the dataframes then merge/join the columns you want back to the first df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *extra* polygons in `gdf_chi_pop` were actually just duplicates of polygons in `gdf_census` from where the two sets intersected.  It turned out the two key functions I needed were `overlay` and `dissolve`, like so:

```
gdf_chi['landuse_index'] = gdf_chi.index.copy()
```

Figure out the intersecting geometry:

```
gdf_chi_pop = gpd.overlay(gdf_census, gdf_chi, how='intersection')
```

Recalculate *extensive* quantity population from *intensive* quantity population density:

```
gdf_chi_pop['population'] = gdf_chi_pop['pop dnsty'] * gdf_chi_pop['geometry'].area / 5280**2
```

Recover original geometry from `gdf_chi` and add populations on regions being joined using `aggfunc`:

```
 gdf_chi_fin = gdf_chi_pop.dissolve(by='landuse_index', aggfunc='sum')
```

Recalculate *intensive* quantity population density

```
gdf_chi_fin['pop dnsty'] = gdf_chi_fin['population'] / gdf_chi_fin['geometry'].area * 5280**2
```

`sjoin` does not create new geometries.  It merely returns the other column values for where the existing geometries intersect.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain geometry of `gdf_chi`, try setting `how` to 'left'.

```
gdf_chi_pop = gpd.sjoin(gdf_chi, gdf_census, how='left',op='intersects')
```

GeoPandas does not differentiate between intensive and extensive properties. It just joins the data from one to the another gdf. No matter the type, it is just copied.